# Set of all infinite bit strings with an equal number of $0$s and $1$s.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Is the set of all infinite bit strings with an equal number of $0$s and $1$s countable or uncountable?

Not sure how to prove that is countable/uncountable. Any hints would be nice.

Comment: An infinite bit string with an equal number of $0$s and $1$s must have infinitely many $0$s and infinitely many $1$s.

Answer (score 5):

What's your definition of "equal number of $0$s and $1$s"?

If you mean the index sets have the same cardinality, then it's definitely uncountable: Its complement is the set where either $0$ or $1$ appears only finitely many times, which is countable, as it's the countable union of finite sets $$\{a_1a_2...|a_n=1, \forall n\ge N\} \cup \{a_1a_2... |a_n=0, \forall n\ge N\}$$

It could mean that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^na_i}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$, where $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ counts the number of $1$'s among $a_1, \cdots, a_n$. This set is also uncountable: thanks to the strong law of large numbers, this set has probability $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Using a stricter definition of “equal number of 0s and 1s” than [Just a user](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465160/set-of-all-infinite-bit-strings-with-an-equal-number-of-0s-and-1s/4465165#4465165):

Let $B$ be the set of all infinitely-long strings consisting of bi-bit strings “01” or “10”.  (So strings starting with 0101, 0110, 1001, and 1010 may be part of this set, but strings starting with any other 4-bit sequence may not.)  Clearly, if $x \in B$, then $x$ will have an equal number of 0's and 1's after any *even* number of bits.

Assume that $B$ is countable.  IOW, we can assign every $x \in B$ to an index $k$ in an ordered sequence $b$.

Now, apply [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).  Let $y \in B$ be an infinite string such that the $n$th bi-bit in $y$ is the complement ($01 \rightarrow 10, 10 \rightarrow 01$) of the corresponding b-bit in $b_n$.  Then $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}, y \ne b_k$, as they must differ in at least two bits.  But this contradicts our assumption that every member of $B$ can be indexed by a $k$.

Therefore, $B$ is uncountable.

Any supersets of $B$, just as the two mentioned in Just a user's post, must also be uncountable.

Comment: Excellent! It's easier to see this way: encode $01$ by $0$ and $10$ by $1$, then  there is a 1-1 correspondence between $B$ and all 0-1 strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

1. Set of all functions $f:\Bbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ is equivalent to ${\mathscr{P}}({\Bbb{N}})$.
2. Then use Cantor's theorem , no injective map from $A$ to ${\mathscr{P}}(A)$ is onto.

Alternative:

$|\{f | f:\Bbb{N}\to\{0,1\}\}|=2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$